# Check GPS signal with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, gps, core-location

how can I check the presence of the GPS signal with Objective-C?

Comment: Platform? On a PC/Mac you would need a library to talk to a GPS receiver, on an iPhone/iPad - there is probably an API

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could check some info on `CLLocationManager`:

> **locationServicesEnabled**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.
>
> `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled`
>
> **significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether significant location change tracking is > available.
>
> `+ (BOOL)significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable`

or...

Use an instance of `CLLocationManager`, start a query, and implement delegate error method.

Answer (score 1):

Core Location hides from you the exact mechanism of location acquisition. There's no way to know whether the location it returns is from cell tower triangulation or Wifi sniffing or from actual GPS.

It does give you some hints, though, the main one being the `.horizontalAccuracy` of the CLLocation object it returns. The smaller a number that is, the more accurate a mechanism was used. Generally speaking a true GPS hit is going to get you inside 100 meters.

So you could turn on CLLocationManager's updates and watch the accuracy of the locations it gives you, and once they get reasonably accurate, you could know you're listening to the satellites.